# ¿Cómo leer el siguiente Array?

Tags: php

Tengo una consulta, a la base de datos que me trae los siguientes datos `["Asistio","3"]["No asistio","1"]["Excusa","1"]` la consulta en PHP sería algo así:

```
  $resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT gender, COUNT(*) AS Cantidad FROM tabledit WHERE idtaller = $taller GROUP BY gender");

    while($result= mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)){
        $encode= json_encode($result);
        echo $encode;
    };
```

El problema está en que la consulta tiene la posibilidad de que me traiga la cantidad de los que asistieron, no asistieron y con excusa, pero también está la posibilidad de que me traiga algo así `["Asistio","4"]["Excusa","1"]`  o también  `["Asistio","5"]` , y ahí es donde no sabría como leer el `array` y asignar a 3 variables, una que sea la cantidad que asistieron, otra que sea la cantidad que no asistieron y la otra con excusa.

Comment: prueba con foreach de toda la vida

Comment: Tienes que recorrer el Array con foreach, en el siguiente enlace encontraras referencias de como hacerlo, [https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php), estas son las cuestiones básicas que uno espera sean leídas de la documentación de PHP.

Comment: Esa consulta no parece traer esos resultados..

Comment: que tal si agregas la tabla , y algunos datos de muestera para tener idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No se si entendí bien tu pregunta pero,este codigo verifica si existe el grupo y guarda su cantidad si no es a si el nombre del grupo se queda a 0

```
 $resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT gender, COUNT(*) AS Cantidad FROM tabledit WHERE idtaller = $taller GROUP BY gender");

        $asistio=0;
        $noasistio=0;
        $excusa=0;
        while($result= mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)){

            if($result[0]=="Asistio"){
               $asistio=$result[1];
            };
            else if($result[0]=="No asistio"){
               $noasistio= $result[1];
            };
            else if($result[0]=="Excusa"){
                $excusa = $result[1];
            };


        };
```